# TinyMCE - разделитель

Tags: tinymce

Пишу следующий код для установки редактора

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
],
toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | pagebreak",
toolbar2: "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
image_advtab: true,
language: 'ru',
pagebreak_separator: '<!--SEPARATOR-->'
```

});

Меня интересует эта строка:

```
pagebreak_separator: '<!--SEPARATOR-->'
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Разделить", то не вставляется SEPARATOR в код. Почему? Что ещё нужно прописать, установить? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что у вас за tinymce, но у меня просто прописывается:

```
 theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,separator,underlinestrikethrough,sub,sup,
  separator,formatselect,fontsizeselect" и т.д.
```

Т.е. слово "separator" так и вписывается.